# Ubuntu 17.10 goes to sleep after just 1 minute

Tags: 17.10, power-management

I installed Ubuntu 17.10 on a brand new HP desktop and it is pretty much unusable. It powers off after 1 minute and no matter how I change the power and/or privacy settings from the UI, it keeps doing it. I also tried some shell commands with no luck. Is there a way to stop this incredible behavior?